# Does the Canon T2i have the same battery as the T1i?

Tags: canon-550d, canon-500d

I need to know if the Canon T2i has the same battery as the T1i. I am borrowing a T1i from a friend and I won't be able to get the camera until the day I need it. I have a T2i and I have a power cord (that plugs into the wall) and several spare batteries. Will the batteries from the T2i fit the T1i?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Canon T2i](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/675617-REG/Canon_4462B001_Canon_EOS_Rebel_T2i.html) actually uses a newer battery pack - the [LP-E8](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/676256-REG/Canon_4515B002_LP_E8_Rechargeable_Lithium_Ion_Battery.html) as opposed to the T1i that used the [LP-E5](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/547868-REG/Canon_3039B001_LP_E5_Rechargeable_Lithium_Ion_Battery.html). The [LP-E8](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/676256-REG/Canon_4515B002_LP_E8_Rechargeable_Lithium_Ion_Battery.html) has better battery performance, but unfortunately you cannot use them interchangeably.

This is from the [PCWorld Review](http://www.pcworld.com/article/201999/canon_eos_rebel_t2i_offers_entrylevel_excellence.html):

> Canon upgraded the battery pack to the LP-E8 instead of the LP-E5 that
>   powers the T1i. The good news is that battery performance is better.
>   The bad news is you can't use any spare LP-E5 batteries you may have.

Comment: Too bad.... :-(

Comment: So does the LP-**E5** has better performance (as stated in your answer)? Or is it the LP-**E8** that is better (as stated in the citation)?

Comment: @BartArondson - Yea sorry. I don't have either camera so my only knowledge is from the citation :)

Answer (score 0):

No, both of the two cameras you mention use different batteries, the T2i (EOS 550D) uses the LP-E8, however the T1i (EOS 500D) uses the older LP-E5

Comment: How does this answer different from the accepted answer?